# Dropbox API v2 - App folder deleted by user after receiving token

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I know that one of the ways to revoke a Token is by deleting the app folder if the app uses the "app folder" permission. If that happens, then a *InvalidAccessTokenException* will be thrown.

Is it absolutely necessary to check during each API call if the app folder exist? or rather there is a setting or flag of some sort to create the folder (before writing to it) whenever it cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure your app `catch`es and handles `InvalidAccessTokenException` for any API call, as this can happen at any time. This will cover both cases: if the user explicitly revoked the app, as well as if the user just deleted the app folder. You don't need to do anything extra for the latter case in particular.

Comment: What do you mean don't need to do anything extra? Don't I need to recreate the folder or the token?

Comment: When you get a `InvalidAccessTokenException`, you can prompt the use to re-authorize the app if they want to continue using the integration, but you don't need to recreate the folder yourself. This is done automatically by Dropbox when the user re-authorizes the app, if the app happens to use the app folder permission.